# Shopify App OAuth Error Whitelisted URL if user is not logged in

Tags: python, shopify

My app was working two weeks ago. If the user is already logged in, I am not getting this error. But, if user is not logged in, I am getting that Redirect URI Whitelisted error.

On checking the issue, I found out that - If user is already logged in, on browser, I am seeing this url -

https://vsanalytics.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/request_grant?client_id=&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F54.218.116.25%3A8080%2Flogin%2Ffinalize%2F&scope=write_products%2Cwrite_orders%2Cwrite_customers%2Cread_checkouts%2Cread_price_rules%2Cwrite_price_rules%2Cread_marketing_events%2Cwrite_marketing_events

And it is working fine.

But, if user is not logged in, I am seeing this - 
https://vsanalytics.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/request_grant?client_id=70ffd0b9d365026205e5a06a7a55788a&redirect_uri=http%253A%252F%252F54.218.116.25%253A8080%252Flogin%252Ffinalize%252F&scope=write_products%252Cwrite_orders%252Cwrite_customers%252Cread_checkouts%252Cread_price_rules%252Cwrite_price_rules%252Cread_marketing_events%252Cwrite_marketing_events

Clearly, redirect uri is double encoded when user is logged in

Comment: Do you have some Python code that has changed since two weeks ago?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Sure halfer. Thanks. 
That problem is solved. Actually, our SSL certificate does not contain chain certificates which was causing this issue.